# How to calculate which view occupies more than half of the screen

Tags: android, android-view, android-recyclerview

I have a `recyclerview` with 3 custom views of my own. RV is scrollable for horizontal and width of the each view equals width of the screen. I want to show, which view is currently displaying (which view occupies more, than a half of the screen). How to do that?

MainScreenActivity.class

```
public class MainScreenActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener, MainScreenView {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

MyAdapter.class

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<ChartDefiner> chartDefiners;
    private DataView dataView;

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ChartView chartView;

        public MyViewHolder(ChartView chartView) {
            super(chartView);
            this.chartView = chartView;
        }
    }

    public MyAdapter(List<ChartDefiner> chartDefiners, DataView dataView) {
        this.chartDefiners = chartDefiners;
        this.dataView = dataView;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ChartView v = (ChartView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chart_layout, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.chartView.initData();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return chartDefiners.size();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented some basic scrolling animation in my app. I used this piece of code and it is working perfectly fine.

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, 
LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);




 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        switch (newState) {

            case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING:
               currentItemPosition=linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
 }
    }
```

Comment: he wants to show more than items of recylcer view ,at the time of Settling of scroll if you calculate the findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition(),it will give the position you want

Comment: It's not worked in my case. In my test app I have 3 view in one rv and SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING was switched only when I bounded a border of all 3 view

Comment: try the same in these states   RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE,  RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING: